# How to get graphql query using DGS

Tags: java, spring, graphql, netflix-dgs

I send such a query using graphiql:

```
{
    project(projectId: "634593f811af096d17579a0d") {
        id
        name
        locations {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

I have such a dataFetcher

```
@DgsQuery
public Project project(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe, @NotNull @InputArgument String projectId) {
    return projectService.findById(projectId);
}
```

I would like to get the query inside the dataFetcher in the same format as I sent it through graphiql. How can I do it?